# How do I add these headers to my python urllib opener?

Tags: python, http, url, urllib2

```
headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'Referer': 'http://www.namestation.com/domain-search?autosearch=1',
    'Origin': 'http://www.namestation.com',
    'Host': 'www.namestation.com',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive'
}
cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
```

> opener.addHeaders(headers)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this may work:

```
def opener():
    cj=cookielib.CookieJar()
    #Process Hadlers
    opener=urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
    opener.addheaders=[
                    ('Accept', 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01'),
                    ('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest'),
                    ('Referer', 'http://www.namestation.com/domain-search?autosearch=1'),
                    ('Host', 'www.namestation.com'),
                    ('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'),
                    ('Connection', 'keep-alive'),
                ]
    return opener
```

Answer (score 6):

Your opener should have an attribute `addheaders`, which is a list of tuples. By default it contains the user agent.

```
opener.addheaders.append(('Host', 'www.namestation.com'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You should turn the dict to the tuple first.

`opener.addHeaders=tuple(items for items in headers.items())`

Comment: This gives the wrong type, instead use `[items for items in headers.items()]`